# Trying to deploy my spring boot application to heroku using cli and i am facing issue

Tags: spring, rest, heroku, boot

what are the dependency or plugins i need to add
to remove this error when deploying to heroku

```
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 1 plugin(s)
[WARNING]
[WARNING]   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.5.0
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
[WARNING]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project kloc_CRM: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException!     

ERROR: Failed to build app with MavenWe're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/!     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.!     Push failed
```

I used  maven site plugin
maven compiler plugin
maven dependency plugin
maven validator plugin
still i am getting this error

Comment: Have you read the error? -> `invalid flag: --release`. You are using a java version on Heroku that doesn't support the new `--release` flag. Make sure that you use a Java version that supports that, you probably use JDK 1.8 on Heroku whereas you should use something like JDK 9 or up.